# Multipeer Connectivity crashes during file transfer when sending peer disconnects

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, multipeer-connectivity

// I have a simple app that uses Multipeer Connectivity to send media files from one device to another. It works well, but the only problem I'm having is if the sending device disconnects, the receiving device crashes — shouldn't there be a way to disconnect or cancel a file transfer? I've included a screenshot with the call stack. The strange thing is the function in the call stack (directly under the point of the crash) is never called, or at least the breakpoints aren't reached (`session(_ session: didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: fromPeer peerID: at localURL:  withError error: )`). How can I prevent this crash from happening?